# Pandas conversion from JSON to Dataframe with data with multiple attributes

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have json data which compiled by attributes(column) and its elements(data) for each.

```
[
    {
        "attribute_id": "a1",
        "attribute_name": "Profailkir Idkir",
        "elements":[
             {
                "formValues": [
                    "0000a634940"
                ],
                "id": "0000a634940"
            },
            {
                "formValues": [
                    "0000c84724"
                ],
                "id": "0000c84724"
            }]
     },
     {
        "attribute_id": "a2",
        "attribute_name": "Profailkir Nama",
        "elements":[
             {
                "formValues": [
                    "'AFIFAH BINTI KHAIRUL JUBRI"
                ],
                "id": "'AFIFAH BINTI KHAIRUL JUBRI"
            },
            {
                "formValues": [
                    "'AINUN JARIAH BINTI HASHIM"
                ],
                "id": "'AINUN JARIAH BINTI HASHIM"
            }]
     }
]
```

but when i tried using

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

the result is become appended only, not extracting the formValues.

[image]

How can I convert into Dataframe in below reading format?

|  | Profailkir Idkir | Profailkir Nama |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0000a634940 | 'AFIFAH BINTI KHAIRUL JUBRI |
| 1 | 0000c84724 | 'AINUN JARIAH BINTI HASHIM |

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the `id` values from each element, you could use a dictionary comprehension on your data to reshape it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ e['attribute_name'] : [ v['id'] for v in e['elements'] ] for e in data })
```

Output:

```
  Profailkir Idkir              Profailkir Nama
0      0000a634940  'AFIFAH BINTI KHAIRUL JUBRI
1       0000c84724   'AINUN JARIAH BINTI HASHIM
```

If you want the `formValues` (and they are of the same length for each attribute), you can modify the code slightly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ e['attribute_name'] : sum([v['formValues'] for v in e['elements'] ], []) for e in data })
```

For your sample data, the result is the same.

Comment: I got error "ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length". This is maybe the case of array of "elements" does not consistent. How to avoid checking the array of elements for each attributes? So if the case that length of array is not same, then leave as NULL..

Comment: @AfifZuhair then you would have to decide which element you wanted to keep, and I'm not sure how you would do that. Also, if the element arrays are of different length, how do you know the values are aligned with each other correctly?

Comment: @AfifZuhair do you want to use the `id` or `formValues` values?

Comment: you're right. It not possible to align. To be exact, ```formValues``` are more used.

Comment: You could pad the length of values (e.g. with `None`) to make them all match? Would that work?

Comment: It might be simpler to resolve this if you can edit your question with some sample data that demonstrates the different lengths